# Is it possible to use NHibernate 4 without db cfg file?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, nhibernate, .net-4.5

So in NHibernate all seems to be configurable without any special configuration (Attributes and code for schema configuration and mapping). Is it possible to configure DB connection (creation in case of SQLite) and thus make NHybernate work without xml configuration file?

Comment: What you mean by special configuration? You can make schema mapping in both *xml files* and , my favourite, **fluent configuration**. By *DB connection* you refer to `connectionString`?

Answer (score 1):

This is called *mapping by code*. Or in other words, something like Entity Framework's *Code-First* approach.

There're various sources. [One might be this (a blog series)](http://notherdev.blogspot.com.es/2012/02/nhibernates-mapping-by-code-summary.html) or [this](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com.es/2011/07/nhibernate-playing-with-mapping-by-code.html) (from Fabio Maulo, an ex-maintainer of NHibernate).

It's not an actual answer pointing you to *Google* but just look for *NHibernate mapping by code* and you'll find a lot of how-tos.

Comment: I was intrested not in per object mappings but for general configureation mapping like this [one](https://github.com/nkmajeti/nhibernate/blob/master/nhibernate/src/NHibernate.Config.Templates/SQLite.cfg.xml)

Comment: @DuckQueen http://blog.andrewawhitaker.com/blog/2014/08/28/getting-nhibernate-up-and-running-quickly/